# Add rows to data frame such that there are exactly n repeats of each unique value?

Tags: r

I am using R to analyze a CSV file with ~100,000 rows that look like this. I'd appreciate any help at all—I'm really new to this.

This is my table:

```
Row1 -> Group, Position, Frequency
Row2 -> 192, 1, 0.2
Row3 -> 192, 2, 0.3
Row4 -> 192, 3, 0.1
Row5 -> 193, 4, 0.5
Row6 -> 193, 5, 0.6
Row7 -> 194, 6, 0.2
Row8 -> 194, 7, 0.4
Row9 -> 195, 8, 0.9
Row10 -> 196, 9, 0.8
```

I want each value in the group column to repeat exactly three times. 192 repeats three times, but 194 repeats twice, while 195 and 196 only occur once. I want to add rows such that if there aren't three repeats of a value in the group column, it will add rows to make a total of three repeats and leave the cells in the other columns of that row blank (or `NA`). So the end result looks like this:

```
Row1 -> Group, Position, Frequency
Row2 -> 192, 1, 0.2
Row3 -> 192, 2, 0.3
Row4 -> 192, 3, 0.1
Row5 -> 193, 4, 0.5
Row6 -> 193, 5, 0.6
Row7 -> 193, NA, NA
Row8 -> 194, 6, 0.2
Row9 -> 194, 7, 0.4
Row10-> 194, NA, NA
Row11 -> 195, 8, 0.9
Row12 -> 195, NA, NA
Row13 -> 195, NA, NA
Row14 -> 196, 9, 0.8
Row15 -> 196, NA, NA
Row16 -> 196, NA, NA
```

Answer (score 2):

With the tidyverse, you can use `tidyr::complete` to add missing combinations of rows:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data_frame(Row = c("Row2", "Row3", "Row4", "Row5", "Row6", "Row7", "Row8", "Row9", "Row10"), 
                 Group = c(192, 192, 192, 193, 193, 194, 194, 195, 196), 
                 Position = 1:9, 
                 Frequency = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.6, 0.2, 0.4, 0.9, 0.8))

df_filled <- df %>% 
    group_by(Group) %>% 
    mutate(i = row_number()) %>% 
    complete(i = 1:3)

df_filled
#> # A tibble: 15 x 5
#> # Groups:   Group [5]
#>    Group     i   Row Position Frequency
#>    <dbl> <int> <chr>    <int>     <dbl>
#>  1   192     1  Row2        1       0.2
#>  2   192     2  Row3        2       0.3
#>  3   192     3  Row4        3       0.1
#>  4   193     1  Row5        4       0.5
#>  5   193     2  Row6        5       0.6
#>  6   193     3  <NA>       NA        NA
#>  7   194     1  Row7        6       0.2
#>  8   194     2  Row8        7       0.4
#>  9   194     3  <NA>       NA        NA
#> 10   195     1  Row9        8       0.9
#> 11   195     2  <NA>       NA        NA
#> 12   195     3  <NA>       NA        NA
#> 13   196     1 Row10        9       0.8
#> 14   196     2  <NA>       NA        NA
#> 15   196     3  <NA>       NA        NA
```

Comment: Simple and elegant

Comment: Thank you so much!! This was very helpful :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$Group), function(a){
        data.frame(Group = rep(a$Group[1], 3),
                   Position= a$Position[1:3],
                   Frequency = a$Frequency[1:3])
}))
#      Group Position Frequency
#192.1   192        1       0.2
#192.2   192        2       0.3
#192.3   192        3       0.1
#193.1   193        4       0.5
#193.2   193        5       0.6
#193.3   193       NA        NA
#194.1   194        6       0.2
#194.2   194        7       0.4
#194.3   194       NA        NA
#195.1   195        8       0.9
#195.2   195       NA        NA
#195.3   195       NA        NA
#196.1   196        9       0.8
#196.2   196       NA        NA
#196.3   196       NA        NA
```

DATA

```
df = structure(list(Group = c(192L, 192L, 192L, 193L, 193L, 194L, 
194L, 195L, 196L), Position = 1:9, Frequency = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 
0.5, 0.6, 0.2, 0.4, 0.9, 0.8)), .Names = c("Group", "Position", 
"Frequency"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this!